# Is there a statement to calculate the time difference between the reading in the database?

Tags: mysql

i am trying to make RFID access control with 2 readers as something similar to a two factor authentication system.
I have been trying to calculate the time difference between two timestamps from different RFID readers in the database. I have tried many different ways to query the results, but keep getting a zero or errors.

I have tried several query commands to calculate the time difference ex:timestampdiff with various combinations. I have shown some of the ones I've tried.

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tag_logs
   WHERE tag_logs = tag_no
   BETWEEN timestamp ('timestamp', 'timestamp');

SELECT *
FROM tag_logs
WHERE timediff is BETWEEN (MINUTE_SECOND,'timestamp', 'timestamp' )
```

I expected the output to calculate the number of rows and check if it is equals to greater than a specific number.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MySQL TIMEDIFF function](https://database.guide/timediff-examples-mysql/):

> From a quick google search:
>
> > The MySQL TIMEDIFF() function returns the difference between two time or datetime values. The way it works is, you provide the two values to compare, and TIMEDIFF() subtracts the second value from the first, then returns the result as a time value.

EDIT:

After rethinking your problem, it seems evident that your task is more complex than it seems at first glance. If you want to check the difference between two RFID accesses, it's a lot more difficult. If you want to query for all the records between one time and another, it's a lot less difficult. Your first example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tag_logs
WHERE tag_logs = tag_no
BETWEEN timestamp ('timestamp', 'timestamp');
```

is only going to add the values of the two timestamps, which is going to result in a date more than twice as far from the unix epoch as we are now; and since you haven't supplied a second value for the between keyword, it's going to choose that to be 00:00:00 (0 epoch-time, 1st of January 1970), and every record will be returned.

Your second example:

```
SELECT *
FROM tag_logs
WHERE timediff is BETWEEN (MINUTE_SECOND,'timestamp', 'timestamp' )
```

doesn't exactly make too much sense either. I see where you're going with this, but it seems thrown together from examples on the internet. What you want is probably something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tag_logs
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN timestamp1 AND timestamp2.
```

You seem to want to calculate the time difference though for each record though.

What you want is something that would go row-by-agonizing-row and calculate the timestamp difference between the two records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  (SELECT p1.id,
       p1.time,
       TIMEDIFF(p2.time, p1.time)
           AS timedifference
       FROM tag_logs p1
       INNER JOIN tag_logs p2
       ON p2.id = (p1.id + 1)
ORDER BY p1.id ASC) time_table
WHERE time_table.timedifference >= '00:05:00'
```

[Here is a functioning SQL fiddle for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda8d8/1)

And try #2!

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT p1.id, p1.ts, TIMEDIFF(timestamp(p2.ts), timestamp(p1.ts)) AS timedifference
       FROM tag_logs p1
       INNER JOIN tag_logs p2
       ON p2.id = (p1.id + 1)
ORDER BY p1.id ASC) time_table
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(time_table.timedifference) >= TIME_TO_SEC('00:10:00')
```

[And another SQL Fiddle!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda8d8/31)

37 iterations later....

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT p1.id, p1.ts, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p2.ts) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p1.ts) AS timedifference
       FROM tag_logs p1
       INNER JOIN tag_logs p2
       ON p2.id = (p1.id + 1)
ORDER BY p1.id ASC) time_table
WHERE time_table.timedifference >= TIME_TO_SEC('1:00:00')
```

Comment: I have tried the TIMEDIFF() with specific time period of 5mins but it ends up giving me the full database as my query

Comment: Try reversing the order of your timestamps.

Comment: reversing the timestamps gives the same result which is the full database.

Comment: and the above COUNT() code by @var firstName is displaying result as 0

Comment: Well are there any records where the time difference is greater than 5 minutes?

Comment: Can you supply a few records as sample data in csv/pipe-delimited?

Comment: yes there are I also changed the time to check if there was a different output

Comment: Try the most recent code in my reply. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda8d8/55

Comment: still the same results, i think it is because i do not have a column that has unique data, my db has three columns, tag number, reader id and timestamp

Comment: You need to have a primary key. This is usually called the id column and is an autoincrement non-null int.